Oracle 23: users and databases
In previous versions of Oracle, a schema was owned by a database user and had the same name as that user. Is that true in Oracle 23? I wonder whether a user in Oracle 23 can access several ‘databases’ as it happens in, for example, MySQL.
Thanks

In Oracle Database 23ai, the relationship between users and schemas remains consistent with previous versions: each user has an associated schema that shares the same name. This means that when a user is created, a schema with the same name is automatically established to store that user’s database objects.
Unlike systems such as MySQL, where a single user can access multiple databases, in Oracle, each database instance contains its own schemas, and each schema is owned by a single user. Therefore, a user in Oracle Database 23ai does not access multiple "databases" as in MySQL; instead, they interact with objects within their own schema or, if granted the appropriate permissions, with objects in other schemas within the same database instance.
Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/23/coredoc/prepare-database-user-and-privileges-oracle.html#GUID-09A64B84-23C6-4EDD-ABC0-D82ED62068BA
Hope it helps.

Thanks Eduardo. I have read that "Common users have access to
their various containers and are in the CDB (container database). Local users are specific to a PDB (pluggable database). Perhaps I could get what I want creating a common user that have access to several PDB? does it make sense?

Yes, it makes sense! In Oracle Database 23ai (and previous Multitenant architecture versions), common users and local users are used to manage access across different containers in a multitenant environment:
Common Users:
Is created in the CDB root (CDB$ROOT) and exists in all PDBs (Pluggable Databases) within the Container Database (CDB).
They have access to multiple PDBs if the appropriate privileges are granted.
The name of a common user always starts with C## (e.g., C##ADMIN), unless this restriction is explicitly disabled.
Local Users:
A local user is specific to a single PDB.
